# Reuse @Mapping definitions in Mapstruct

Tags: kotlin, mapstruct

I have the mapper below that's working fine, but I was wondering if there's any way to define once and reuse the duplicate mappings on `remoteToNewLocalApp` and `remoteToLocalAppUpdate`.

```kotlin
@Mapper
interface AppMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "appId", source = "atemsPackage.appId", defaultExpression = "java(packageId)")
    @Mapping(target = "appOnRemote", constant = "true")
    fun remoteToNewLocalApp(atemsPackage: AtemsPackage, packageId: String): LocalApp

    @Mapping(target = "appId", source = "atemsPackage.appId", defaultExpression = "java(packageId)")
    @Mapping(target = "appOnRemote", constant = "true")
    fun remoteToLocalAppUpdate(atemsPackage: AtemsPackage, packageId: String): LocalAppRemoteUpdate

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE: AppMapper =
            Mappers.getMapper(AppMapper::class.java)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```kotlin
@Mapper
interface AppMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "appId", source = "atemsPackage.appId", defaultExpression = "java(packageId)")
    @Mapping(target = "appOnRemote", constant = "true")
    fun remoteToNewLocalApp(atemsPackage: AtemsPackage, packageId: String): LocalApp

    @InheritConfiguration(name = "remoteToNewLocalApp")
    fun remoteToLocalAppUpdate(atemsPackage: AtemsPackage, packageId: String): LocalAppRemoteUpdate

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE: AppMapper =
            Mappers.getMapper(AppMapper::class.java)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@InheritConfiguration` on the second mapper method. Here is a Java example taken from the official documentation.

```java
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "numberOfSeats", source = "seatCount")
    Car carDtoToCar(CarDto car);

    @InheritConfiguration
    void carDtoIntoCar(CarDto carDto, @MappingTarget Car car);
}
```

Further reading can be found in the [official documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-configuration-inheritance).